# How to read data from an Ajax web service with Qt?

Tags: ajax, qt

I would like to process some data in a Qt application. This data can be found on a web page which uses Ajax to dynamically update itself.

For example, the page itself is www.example.com, and it uses Ajax to load data from www.example.com/data, which is a plain text file. If I view www.example.com in a browser, I can clearly see when the data is updated.

The brute force solution would be to just call the `QWebView`'s `load(QUrl("www.example.com/data"))` every couple of seconds, or every time its `loadFinished()` signal is emitted, but that would be a waste of bandwidth, an I will be downloading the same data over and over. The time between updates could theoretically be a few seconds, but it could also be minutes, hours, or longer.

Is there a possibility to only reload the data when the page is updated?

Comment: Unless your website supports websockets, your brute-force solution is the only solution. Traditional websites do not have a mechanism for broadcasting notifications of changes.

Comment: @RobbieE : in this case, how does the browser know when it needs to refresh the data? Are the browsers also employing blind polling? I'm not that experienced in web technology, but I always though that everything what the browser knows can be known by any program., except when dealing with cryptography, certificates, etc. The problem I would like to solve doesn't involve any form of cryptography.

Comment: Traditional AJAX connections are once-off, so, yes, if the browser wants to know if something has changed, it needs to query the server. This changes with websockets though, where the server can communicate with the browser without first being queried by the browser.

Comment: @RobbieE : This seems to be the answer then. If you post it as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traditional AJAX model uses the following sequence of events:

1. Browser opens connection
2. Browser sends request
3. Server sends response
4. Server closes connection

Because the connection is closed, there is no way for the server to notify your browser if any data have changed. In order to get this information, you have no option but to query the server periodically.

As you mentioned in your question, this is not very efficient since you can waste a lot of bandwidth if nothing changes for a long while.

[WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) is a more up-to-date technology that tries to overcome this inefficiency and [Qt has a module](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebsockets-index.html) that caters for this.

Unfortunately, it's not universal yet so, if you want to use WebSocket technology on a third-party server, you need to have traditional AJAX code to fall back on in case WebSockets are not supported.

EDIT:
Unfortunately, WebSockets are not the golden solution. It's still up to the server to have been programmed to send out notifications of changes. If the server does not have this feature, it won't matter if you're using WebSockets or traditional AJAX, you'll still have to keep querying for changes.